# How do I get pacman to use my custom PKGBUILDs when updating?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

I customized a `PKGBUILD` for Apache, ran `makepkg` and installed it with `pacman -U httpd.tar.xz`, which worked fine. A few months later I upgraded my system with `pacman -Syu` which used the system-default configuration for Apache which broke my web server. How do I tell pacman to always use my custom compilation settings so I don’t have to manually upgrade every time a new version is released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by installing [yaourt and customizepkg](http://versia.com/2009/09/arch-linux-yaourt-customizepkg-beauty/), which allows me to have the best of both worlds: the latest and greatest versions from the official repositories, automatically patched to my specific needs.

Comment: This solution no longer works. Any alternative? Both yaourt and customizepkg seem to be discontinued.

Answer (score 10):

Pacman won't upgrade Apache using your customized PKGBUILD; you will have to do that manually using [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ABS). What you can do, is prevent pacman from overwriting your customized package.

To expand on [Renan's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32131/6761), if you have more than one package that you wish to prevent `pacman` updating, you can include a `groups` field in the respective PKGBUILDs and then, in `/etc/pacman.conf` use the `IgnoreGroup` line.

This gives you a little more control for multiple packages, without having to remember to edit `pacman.conf` as you add and remove custom PKGBUILDs.

As an example, in your PKGBUILDs, you could use:

```
groups=('modified')
```

and in `/etc/pacman.conf`:

```
IgnoreGroup = modified
```

Answer (score 2):

You can edit `/etc/pacman.conf` and add the name of your package to the `IgnorePkg` line. That way, pacman will not touch your package upon upgrading.